# Xamarin.Forms can't install Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client.SQLiteStore 2.1.1

Tags: c#, azure, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Good morning all,

I am following the [instructions on the azure site](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-xamarin-forms-get-started-offline-data/#enable-offline-sync-functionality-in-the-quickstart-solution) for adding offline sync capability in a Xamarin.Forms application.

I have added the package to the PCL without issue but when trying to add to the iOS client project I am getting the following error:

`Could not install package 'Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client.SQLiteStore 2.1.1'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.`

My project is well established in terms of completed code base so I downloaded the getting started app to test from scratch and the same issue remains.

Please help

Jordan Mazurke

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks lite something is wrong with package 2.1.1.
Install version 2.1.0 instead and it should work!

Answer (score 0):

See also [Unable to install Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client.SQLiteStore 2.1.1 into Xamarin.iOS project with NuGet 2.12](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/3354)